# Is there a command that can be run from a cygwin shell to print out an xml file with color highlighting?

Tags: xml, shell, cygwin

Is there a command that can be run from a cygwin shell to print out an xml file with color highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

Use gvim!

If on first editing the file it appears in plain black and white, select 'XML' from the syntax menu.

Play with the 'Edit'->'Color Scheme' menu until you find a style taht suits you.

Then use the 'Syntax' -> 'Convert to HTML' and save the results.